# Eliminate duplicates in PLSQL / Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble building a query where subitems occur. I attach below the data and the expected end result.
Important thing is fact that SubitemID is not a constant. So I cannot put in my query thing like "subitemid like itemid+1".
Here is my Table:

| ItemID | SubitemID | Category | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | X1 | 116113 | 115 |
| X | X2 | 116113 | 115 |
| X | X1 | 222540 | 100 |
| X | X2 | 222540 | 100 |
| Y | Y1 | 116113 | 204,58 |
| Y | Y2 | 116113 | 204,58 |
| Y | Y4 | 222540 | 500 |
| Y | Y5 | 222540 | 500 |

I would like to sum Values for each type of Category. So the result should be:

| ItemID | Category | Sum of Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 116113 | 115 |
| X | 222540 | 100 |
| Y | 116113 | 204,58 |
| Y | 222540 | 500 |

In other words I need to sum 1 row from each Category, because Value is constant per every ItemID in every category.

---

EDIT:
My query is below:

```
   SELECT ItemID
    ,Category
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 116113 THEN ROUND(Value,4) else 0 end) as "Summary_cat1"
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN Category = 222540 THEN ROUND(Value,4) else 0 end) as "Summary_cat2"
,SUM(CASE WHEN Category in (116113,222540) THEN ROUND(Value,4) else 0 end) as "Summary_cat3"
    FROM TABLE
    GROUP BY ItemID, Category
```

Expected results:

| ItemID | Category | Summary_cat1 | Summary_cat2 | Summary_cat3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 116113 | 115 | 100 | 215 |
| X | 222540 | 115 | 100 | 215 |
| Y | 116113 | 204,58 | 500 | 704,58 |
| Y | 222540 | 204,58 | 500 | 704,58 |

Comment: is it just a case of `select ... from (select distinct itemid, category, value from your_table) yt group by ...`? I.e. get a list of distinct rows first, then do your grouping

Comment: Thank you @Boneist. This is a great Idea that I had forgotten about.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values always be the same across records sharing the same item and category, a distinct query should work here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ItemID, Category, Value
FROM yourTable;
```

If, on the other hand, you really want to *sum* the values, then you should be using:

```sql
SELECT ItemID, Category, SUM(Value) AS SumOfValue
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ItemID, Category;
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. I think my explanation of the problem was wrong. I just edited my post to make it more clarify. It's still just a model of my problem, but more accurate than before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` analytic functions to get the two separate prices per category.

NOTE: This query will only work if there EXACTLY 2 different values per item.

```sql
WITH
    items (ItemID,
           SubitemID,
           Category,
           VALUE)
    AS
        (SELECT 'X', 'X1', '116113', 115 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'X', 'X2', '116113', 115 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'X', 'X1', '222540', 100 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'X', 'X2', '222540', 100 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Y', 'Y1', '116113', 204.58 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Y', 'Y2', '116113', 204.58 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Y', 'Y4', '222540', 500 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Y', 'Y5', '222540', 500 FROM DUAL)
  SELECT DISTINCT
         itemid,
         category,
         FIRST_VALUE (VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid)     AS summary_cat1,
         LAST_VALUE (VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid)      AS summary_cat2,
           FIRST_VALUE (VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid)
         + LAST_VALUE (VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid)    AS summary_cat3
    FROM items i
ORDER BY itemid, category;


ITEMID    CATEGORY       SUMMARY_CAT1    SUMMARY_CAT2    SUMMARY_CAT3
_________ ___________ _______________ _______________ _______________
X         116113                  115             100             215
X         222540                  115             100             215
Y         116113               204.58             500          704.58
Y         222540               204.58             500          704.58
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately sometimes I have more than 2 categories. But your solution works in the terms you mentioned.

Comment: Can you update your sample data and the expected output for what the result should be if there are more than 2 categories? What should it look like if some items have 2 categories, and some items have 3 (or greater)?